# Exclude certain files from Atom Tree View ignore

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

With Atom's Tree View package, its [easy](https://discuss.atom.io/t/ignored-names-still-show-in-tree-view/219) to hide ignored files and VCS ignored files.

***How can I exclude certain files from this ignore?***

Why?

I still want have access to files like those contained in `node_modules`, ( to know import paths, inspect package ReadMes ect. ), but I don't want to check them into git. Since they're not checked into git, I cant inspect those packages because they're hidden by Tree View.

Is there a way I can exclude certain names from the Tree View ignore?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Here is an example:

```
Preferences -> Settings > Core Settings > Ignored Names: *.pyc, *.tmp

Preferences -> Settings > Packages > tree-view > check Hide Ignored names
```

Comment: I'm looking to exclude files from version controlled ignored names. Your solution allows me to hide files, but not to prevent certain ones from being hidden.  In my question, I'm asking how to prevent those files from being hidden.

Comment: hmm, what about uncheck "Hide VCS Ignored Files" and just use the "Ignored Names" list?

Comment: Then I would have manually maintain this list or each project instead of leveraging the `.gitignores` I already have. That would be a lot of maintenance and wouldn't allow me to have project specific rules. It would make switching between projects hell.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @wisbucky is the correct one.

But if you want to hide files from `.gitignore` from `tree-view` by default and be able to display it with a keyboard shortcut, here is your solution :

> - You can toggle whether either VCS ignored files or ignored names are displayed in the Tree View using the `tree-view:toggle-vcs-ignored-files` and `tree-view:toggle-ignored-names` commands, respectively
> - The `tree-view:toggle-vcs-ignored-files` command is mapped to `I` by default when the Tree View is focused

Source : [lee-dohm on github](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/7513)

Comment: The shortcut is lowercase: 'i' not 'I'.